# rosdep install showing independency/not available

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i got error after running  `rosdep install`

```
asus@asus-X556UQK:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths /home/asus/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
amcl: [python3-pykdl] defined as "not available" for OS version [xenial]
```

how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375511/rosdep-install-showing-independency/not-available/) by [anonymous72456](https://answers.ros.org/users/72456/anonymous72456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-06**:
Just to make sure: do you *need* to build AMCL from source?

On Kinetic, it's available as a Deb package and `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-amcl` should install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to build the `noetic-devel` version on Ubuntu Xenial/ROS Kinetic?

This is the dependency declaration in `noetic-devel` (from [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/4a3d261daa4e7eafa40bf7e4505f8aa8678d7bd7/amcl/package.xml)):

> ```
> <test_depend>python3-pykdl</test_depend>
> ```

The `kinetic-devel` version doesn't have this dependency.

If you want to build `amcl` from source on Xenial, you probably want to build the Kinetic version.

Alternatively: you'll have to update the dependency list to be Kinetic/Xenial compatible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-04-06**:
Basically, what he said :-) (Posted as an answer but was late...)

[`python3-pykdl` is not available on xenial](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L6717-L6721).

Note that for xenial and thus ROS kinetic (I'm assuming your using that, you haven't specified this anywhere), the default python version is Python2.7. You should make sure to only use packages that rely on Python 2. Otherwise you might run into a lot of errors.

My guess is you downloaded the `amcl` source code from the `noetic-devel` branch. You should probably go back to the `kinetic-devel` branch. (You could obviously comment the dependency, as it is a test dependency only. It might work then, or it might not. Who knows....)

In the long run, you should probably upgrade from xenial/kinetic to something else (I'd suggest focal/noetic), as kinetic is EOL end of the month and won't receive any updates and fixes anyways...